# Switchmap keep having TypeError

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

i'm trying to create an Observable that returns a UserEntity from Firestore login Promise. 
I keep having this message :

> ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was
>   expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

this.userRepository.getOne(res.user.uid) works correctly (tested separatly).

Can anyone explain me what is happening ?

```
loginObservable(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserEntity> {
return fromPromise(this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password))
  .pipe(
    tap(val => console.log(`1 BEFORE MAP: ${val.user.uid}`)),
    catchError(e => {
      console.log("error : " + e.toString());
      throw(e);
    }),
    switchMap(res => {
      console.log(`1 BEFORE MAP: ${res.user.uid}`);
      return this.userRepository.getOne(res.user.uid);
    }),
    catchError(e => {
      console.log("error : " + e.toString());
      throw(e);
    }),
    tap(val => console.log(`2 AFTER MAP: ${val}`))
  );
}
```

getOne returns an observable and is Ok.

```
getOne(id: string): Observable<UserEntity> {
  return this.getCollection()
   .doc<UserEntity>(id)
   .get()
   .pipe(
    tap(val => console.log(`BEFORE MAP: ${val}`)),
    map(res => UserEntityAdapter.from(res.id, res.data())),
    tap(val => console.log(`after MAP: ${val}`)),
   );
}
```

adapter code :

```
export class UserEntityAdapter {
 static from(id: string, snapshot: any): UserEntity {
  return {
   id,
   name: snapshot.name,
   firstName: snapshot.firstName,
   phoneNumber: snapshot.phoneNumber,
   gender: snapshot.gender,
   urlPhotoPublic: snapshot.urlPhotoPublic,
 };
}
}
```

Comment: replacing this.userRepository.getOne(res.user.uid); by of({}) make it works but ...

Comment: `.getOne()` probably doesn't return either Observable nor Promise

Comment: i've put the function getOne in answer

Comment: @mcfly, looks like, you have not

Comment: a clever guy deleted it. Love stackoverflow mods...

Comment: added it again...

Comment: What is the code for 'getCollection()'

Comment: it's firebase code returning : database.collection('users'); Nothing strange here